# Typeorm bulk insert

Tags: typeorm

I have the following Group entity

```
export class Group {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', unique: true })
  name: string;
}
```

I am trying to implement a bulk insert where only groups with new names would get inserted, while existing one would just get returned without any operation performed on them.

I managed to get this working as follows:

```
await this
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .insert()
  .into(Group)
  .values(groups)
  .orUpdate({
    conflict_target: ['name'],
    overwrite: ['name'],
   })
   .execute();
```

But it can not work.why?

Answer (score 0):

When I set unique key in db.It is work.